Counting the instances of IDs where i got from a different cte in another table
I'm trying to make this session counter that counts the number of sessions a user has had before the date of this session (if he used a coupon) so i started by getting a list of of users that used a coupon using a cte then i try counting the number session he's had before the creation date of the coupon he's using but it always shows up as zero which is impossible. I'm kinda new to sql but i know that the problem isn't that hard which is why it's making me angry at myslef
We'er using MariaDb
I tried stuff like diffrent types of joins and diffrent kinds of funcutions but i couldnt get it to work i tried chat gpt but that didn't help at all.
What i wanted is to have the invoice table but just with the the added column that counts the number of sessions a user has had before his current session
if anyone can point out the mistakes i made and give me advice on how to fix them would be greatly appreciated
this was my latest try:
WITH coupon_sessions AS (
    -- Get all rows where the client used a coupon
    SELECT
        i.pkInvoiceID,
        i.fkClientServiceID,
        i.fkCouponID,
        i.fldDateTime AS invoice_date,
        tt.fldDate AS sessionDate,
        c.fldCreatedDateTime,
        c.fldCreatedBy
    FROM
        tbl_invoice i
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_coupon c ON i.fkCouponID = c.pkCouponID
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_client_service_timeslot ct ON i.fkClientServiceID = ct.pfClientServiceID
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_therapist_timeslot tt ON ct.fkTimeslotID = tt.pkTimeslotID
    WHERE
        i.fkCouponID IS NOT NULL
        AND c.fldCreatedBy in (164908 , 109979, 183378, 142713,96694)
),
client_session_counts AS (
    -- For each client and coupon, count the finished sessions that happened before the coupon's creation date
    SELECT
        cs.fkClientServiceID,
        cs.fkCouponID,
        cs.invoice_date
        cs.sessionDate,
        cs.fldCreatedDateTime,
        COUNT(cs.pkInvoiceID) AS sessionCountBeforeCoupon
    FROM
        coupon_sessions cs
    RIGHT JOIN
        tbl_invoice i ON cs.fkClientServiceID = i.fkClientServiceID
        AND cs.fkCouponID = i.fkCouponID
        AND cs.invoice_date
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_client_service_timeslot ct ON i.fkClientServiceID = ct.pfClientServiceID
    LEFT JOIN
        tbl_therapist_timeslot tt ON ct.fkTimeslotID = tt.pkTimeslotID
    WHERE
        tt.fldDate < CAST(cs.fldCreatedDateTime AS DATE)
        AND ct.fldStatus = 'finished'
    GROUP BY
        cs.fkClientServiceID, cs.fkCouponID
)
-- Select the final result
SELECT
    i2.pkInvoiceID,
    i2.fkClientServiceID,
    i2.fkCouponID,
    COALESCE(csc.sessionCountBeforeCoupon, 0) AS sessionCountBeforeCoupon
FROM
    tbl_invoice i2
LEFT JOIN
    client_session_counts csc ON i2.fkClientServiceID = csc.fkClientServiceID
    AND i2.fkCouponID = csc.fkCouponID
WHERE
    i2.fkCouponID IS NOT NULL


The main issue was how the query was connecting the different parts of your data. We've made it more straightforward, focusing on finding sessions that happened before a coupon was created. We also tidied up some grouping to make sure we're counting things accurately.
If you're still getting zeros, double-check that your dates and relationships between tables are correct. If things still look weird, try running parts of the query separately to see what's going on step-by-step.
WITH coupon_sessions AS ( 
SELECT 
    i.pkInvoiceID, 
    i.fkClientServiceID, 
    i.fkCouponID, 
    i.fldDateTime AS invoice_date, 
    tt.fldDate AS sessionDate, 
    c.fldCreatedDateTime, 
    c.fldCreatedBy 
FROM tbl_invoice i 
LEFT JOIN tbl_coupon c ON i.fkCouponID = c.pkCouponID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_client_service_timeslot ct ON i.fkClientServiceID = ct.pfClientServiceID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_therapist_timeslot tt ON ct.fkTimeslotID = tt.pkTimeslotID 
WHERE 
    i.fkCouponID IS NOT NULL 
    AND c.fldCreatedBy in (164908 , 109979, 183378, 142713,96694) 
), 
client_session_counts AS ( 
SELECT 
    i.fkClientServiceID, 
    i.fkCouponID,
    c.fldCreatedDateTime, 
    COUNT(i.pkInvoiceID) AS sessionCountBeforeCoupon 
FROM tbl_invoice i
JOIN tbl_coupon c ON i.fkCouponID = c.pkCouponID
JOIN tbl_client_service_timeslot ct ON i.fkClientServiceID = ct.pfClientServiceID 
JOIN tbl_therapist_timeslot tt ON ct.fkTimeslotID = tt.pkTimeslotID 
WHERE 
    tt.fldDate < c.fldCreatedDateTime 
    AND ct.fldStatus = 'finished'
GROUP BY 
    i.fkClientServiceID, 
    i.fkCouponID,
    c.fldCreatedDateTime  
) 
SELECT 
i2.pkInvoiceID, 
i2.fkClientServiceID, 
i2.fkCouponID, 
COALESCE(csc.sessionCountBeforeCoupon, 0) AS sessionCountBeforeCoupon 
FROM tbl_invoice i2 
LEFT JOIN client_session_counts csc 
  ON i2.fkClientServiceID = csc.fkClientServiceID 
  AND i2.fkCouponID = csc.fkCouponID 
WHERE i2.fkCouponID IS NOT NULL;

